Reproducing the "Compare" Feature in TradingView with Pine Script

How can I reproduce this exact same chart in TradingView (TV) using Pine Script?
To reproduce the chart natively in TV: Open the BTCUSDT chart > Click on the plus button (Compass or Add symbol) > Select ETHUSDT > Set the same % scale.
The two resulting graphs will coincide on the far left of the screen. From there, they may diverge depending on price variations.
My goal:
I want to programmatically reproduce this same behavior using Pine Script, comparing two or more symbols.
